# IMAP status on not existing folder

Tags: imap, mailkit, dovecot

I am getting this IMAP response. Notice the folders INBOX.INBOX.ooo and INBOX.INBOX.dfgdfg. INBOX.INBOX folder doesn't exists and it is just a placeholder (NonExistent) folder.

```
C: A00000096 STATUS INBOX (UIDVALIDITY HIGHESTMODSEQ)
S: * STATUS INBOX (UIDVALIDITY 1491227400 HIGHESTMODSEQ 17436)
S: A00000096 OK Status completed (0.001 + 0.000 secs).
C: A00000097 LIST "" "INBOX.*" RETURN (SUBSCRIBED CHILDREN STATUS (UIDVALIDITY))
S: * LIST (\Subscribed \HasNoChildren \UnMarked) "." INBOX.INBOX.ooo
S: * STATUS INBOX.INBOX.ooo (UIDVALIDITY 1491227902)
S: * LIST (\HasNoChildren \UnMarked) "." INBOX.INBOX.dfgdfg
S: * STATUS INBOX.INBOX.dfgdfg (UIDVALIDITY 1491227900)
S: A00000097 OK List completed (0.001 + 0.000 secs).
```

However I can select this folder

```
A00000092 SELECT INBOX.INBOX (CONDSTORE)
S: * OK [CLOSED] Previous mailbox closed.
S: * FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Seen \Draft)
S: * OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Seen \Draft \*)] Flags permitted.
S: * 554 EXISTS
S: * 0 RECENT
S: * OK [UIDVALIDITY 1491227400] UIDs valid
S: * OK [UIDNEXT 18263] Predicted next UID
S: * OK [HIGHESTMODSEQ 17436] Highest
S: A00000092 OK [READ-WRITE] Select completed (0.001 + 0.000 secs).
```

So it appears that INBOX.INBOX is actually INBOX folder because UIDVALIDITY match and I can see the emails there. This is very confusing and it is messing my internal cache. Can someone explain what is going on?

UPDATE:
This might give some clues to someone

```
C: A00000001 NAMESPACE
S: * NAMESPACE (("INBOX." ".")) NIL NIL
S: A00000001 OK Namespace completed (0.001 + 0.000 secs).
C: A00000002 LIST "" "INBOX"
S: * LIST (\HasChildren) "." INBOX
S: A00000002 OK List completed (0.002 + 0.000 + 0.001 secs).
```

Comment: Your server has a folder aliasing bug?  Why are you selecting INBOX.INBOX if it isn't being returned in the LIST response?

Comment: I am using Dovecot server. I am not selecting this manually, because I am using Mailkit library and I can see the library is doing that.

Comment: What have you done to cause the library to select INBOX.INBOX?  They don't generally open folders you don't tell it to.

Comment: I am trying to understand server behavior not library behavior.

Comment: Yes, it appears to be a bug; Perhaps INBOX.INBOX is an "internal name" used by dovecot, and it is aliased to INBOX as that is required by the IMAP standard.  Perhaps 'dovecot' would be a better tag than mailkit given your last comment.